# Is Starman wearing a seatbelt?

Tags: spacex, falcon-heavy

While staring at the [live feed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aBr2kKAHN6M) of a crash dummy in a convertible in outer space, I was wondering: Is this crash dummy following safety conventions and wearing a seat belt? I somehow doubt that it would help in case of impact with an astroid, but...

[image: starman]

I don't see any seatbelt, but it's not close enough for me to tell.

**Was Starman sent up wearing a seatbelt or not?**

Comment: Why did this get an "opinion based" close vote?

Comment: Related question - is that all that's keeping him in? I doubt it, I'd think they glued (or something) him to the seat just to be positive no movements are made.

Comment: @BruceWayne, that *must* have happened, or how would the arm stay in that super cool position. ;)

Comment: He's not a crash dummy. Crash dummies are intended to crash. Starman has no intention of crashing for the next billion years.

Comment: Neither Starman nor Jenny Hayden wore seatbelts.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NEFYCaKakE

Answer (score 54):

### He most certainly is.

[image: Belt it out baby]

The seatbelt can be seen clearly across both his shoulders. It is currently unclear whether or not the miniature Starman sat on the dashboard has a seatbelt.

Apparently [he is also sewn into the seat](https://www.quora.com/SpaceX-launched-a-Tesla-car-into-space-Were-the-batteries-and-motor-installed-in-the-car/answer/Josh-Boehm). Source is Quora, so meh, but interesting.

Comment: You wouldn't want him to get pulled over in space

Comment: @Dragongeek There's still the issue of speeding.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, the speed limit out there is 6.706e+8 MPH, I don't think he's in any danger of breaking it

Comment: @JosephRogers That won't stop the space police from having faulty radar guns and pulling you over anyway. And you know how hard it is to pull over in space?!?!

Comment: @corsiKa Pulling over in space surely must be to go into orbit

Comment: @JosephRogers [Not in a car over Australia.](https://twitter.com/WA_Police/status/961057061042704384)

Comment: @CeesTimmerman good point, I forgot that Aussie law overrides the laws of physics :D