# When will the starman's live stream end; and why?

Tags: spacex

SpaceX streamed live views of the Starman, headed for mars.

It ended because of either

- Get out of range for transmission
- Run out of batteries
- Humans turned it off

When/where did this happen, and what will be the root cause ?

Comment: Well it ended up ending already :(

Comment: I doubt it was due to range, considering we received live feeds from the moon in 1969, and can get video from the ISS. He's still in LEO which should be plenty close enough to stream footage.

Comment: Rats! It seems to have ended about when the third burn of the 2nd stage was about to happen. [Is Starman wearing a seatbelt?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24874/12102) I wanted to see the seatbelt in action.

Answer (score 0):

It ended right before the 3rd burn, likely they didn't want to give anything away from that. At best it could have lasted 12 hours after launch, due to the batteries. I suspect that SpaceX has more of the feed they will release at some point post-third burn.