# How long will the Tesla Roadster's heliocentric orbit last?

Tags: spacex, orbital-mechanics, tesla-roadster, orbital-decay

The long term prospects for the integrity of the Roadster and to a lesser extent its [seat belted occupant](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24876/12102) have been addressed in the answers and discussion below [Can I drive Elon Musk's Tesla after it's been in space for 100 Years?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24365/12102) However, what about the object's orbit itself?

Must said previously that the orbit will be stable for billions of years. Now that its orbit is closer to the asteroid belt, is there a collision risk? Could the proximity to Jupiter change its orbit, sending it flying into the Sun?

After all, Jupiter's influence on other objects in the asteroid belt [are well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroid_belt).

Comment: Collision risks are ubiquitous but negligible. Orbit will definitely change over time and can only be predicted precisely for a comparatively short amount of time, after that you need "calibration" (i.e. get to know exact location and velocity at one point). This is all unrelated to the last two questions which have been addressed here: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24365/can-i-drive-elon-musks-tesla-after-its-been-in-space-for-100-years?s=9|26.2102

Comment: Yeah i guess so... But I'm not interested in it being roadworthy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I drive Elon Musk's Tesla after it's been in space for 100 Years?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24365/can-i-drive-elon-musks-tesla-after-its-been-in-space-for-100-years)

Comment: @ReactingToAngularVues Does this look better?

Comment: @uhoh Good job on the salvage!

Comment: Just in: ***Scientists believe that radiation will tear the car into pieces within a year.*** without specific sources, found on http://www.foxnews.com/tech/2018/02/08/elon-musk-posts-final-photo-tesla-roadster-headed-to-asteroid-belt.html . There's also another related question: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23883/21562

Comment: That more what I'm after @derwodamaso! Good work everybody. Now for some answers. Not sure should I mark it as duplicate? Although there are space for overlapping answers between the two questions. I do feel it is a distinct question worth more specific answers of it own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably some tens of millions of years.  Billions of years appears unlikely.  Even in the next million years or so, there is a significant chance of colliding with Earth or Venus:

Research [quoted by BBC news](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-43063379) reports:

> That's the conclusion of an analysis by Czech and Canadian researchers.
>
> They calculated that the roadster has a 6% chance of colliding with Earth and a 2.5% probability of hitting Venus over the next million years.

The corresponding paper:

Hanno Reis, Daniel Tamayo, David Vokrouhlicky.  *The random walk of cars and their collision probabilities with planets*. [arXiv:1802.04718](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.04718):

From the abstract:

> We estimate the dynamical lifetime of the Tesla to be a few tens of millions of years.

Comment: Phys.org's write-up of the ArXiv preprint is also interesting. https://phys.org/news/2018-02-tesla-shot-space-collide-earth.html